Effectiveness of rectangular/square wave chirp signal compared to sinusoidal chirp signal for PWM based switching converters
I have a switching converter (DC-AC) built on Simulink and I want to find out its control to output (current) transfer function using the system Identification toolbox in MATLAB/Simulink. I have two main questions, since the converter is PWM based:

Do I use the sine wave chirp signal as an input or use a square/rectangular wave version of the chirp signal or some other signal?

Do I actually need system Identification (and the open loop transfer function), if I have the MATLAB control system toolbox and PID tuner and I can design a z-domain (digital) PID controller without the System Identification Toolbox?



This might be a better question for the EE Stack Exchange.
